# How do I rewrite this code to functional on Game Maker 2?

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

**This error keeps coming up and I don't know how to fix it**

ERROR in
action number 1
of Create Event
for object :

```
 Variable <unknown_object>.inputDirection(100013, -2147483648) not set before reading it.
     at gml_GlobalScript_PlayerStateFree (line 2) - hSpeed = lengthdir_x(inputMagnitude * speedWalk, inputDirection);
    ############################################################################################
    gml_GlobalScript_PlayerStateFree (line 2)

**Here is my code, could somebody pls rewrite it and help me?**

//movement
hSpeed = lengthdir_x(inputMagnitude * speedWalk, inputDirection);
vSpeed = lengthdir_y(inputMagnitude * speedWalk, inputDirection);

PlayerCollision();

//Update Sprite Index
var _oldSprite = sprite_index;
if (inputMagnitude != 0)
{
    direction = inputDirection
    sprite_index = spriteRun;
} else sprite_index = spriteIdle;
if (_oldSprite != sprite_index) localFrame = 0;

//Update Image Index

PlayerAnimateSprite();

//Change State
if (keyActivate)
{
    state = PlayerStateRoll;
    moveDistanceRemaining = distanceRoll
}
```

I'm trying to make a RPG game on Game Maker 2 (first time) lol

Answer (score 0):

If you are watching a tutorial made for an older version of GameMaker, you should be entering your code inside the `function name() { }` that is automatically created for you when you create a script, like so

```
function PlayerStateFree() {
//movement
hSpeed = lengthdir_x(inputMagnitude * speedWalk, inputDirection);
vSpeed = lengthdir_y(inputMagnitude * speedWalk, inputDirection);

PlayerCollision();

//Update Sprite Index
var _oldSprite = sprite_index;
if (inputMagnitude != 0)
{
    direction = inputDirection
    sprite_index = spriteRun;
} else sprite_index = spriteIdle;
if (_oldSprite != sprite_index) localFrame = 0;

//Update Image Index

PlayerAnimateSprite();

//Change State
if (keyActivate)
{
    state = PlayerStateRoll;
    moveDistanceRemaining = distanceRoll
}
}
```